# Subversion: Check out only those files that have changed between a tag and the HEAD

Tags: svn, tags

What SVN command can I use to check out all files that have changed from the last tag to the current HEAD?
To be more precise, I need to build a list of source code files that have changed between the current tag (or HEAD) and the previous tag. The final result will be a list that will provide me with all the code needed to deploy the next version of the application.

Comment: Subversion doesn't really work that way. While it's possible to selectively check out files, it'll require multiple steps best done in a script. But I suspect that isn't what you need in the first place. Try explaining **what** you need accomplished, instead of asking for how to achieve a solution you've already decided upon (which may not be what's needed). See also [XY Problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)

Comment: Fair enough. I need to build a list of source code files that have changed between the current tag or HEAD and the previous tag.  The final result will be a list that will provide me with all the code  needed to deploying the next upgrade to the application. HTH

Comment: You should edit this into your original post.

Comment: My original post has been edited.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems to give me what I need:

svn diff https://myserver.com/trunk https://myserver.com/tags/v5.0

Answer (score 0):

`svn diff --summarize` will give you a list of all files that have changed between the two "places" (or points in time) that you give it.